# Spring Boot WebMvcTest require EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit5

Why simple `@WebMvcTest` require Entity manager to be run?

I have following controller test

```
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void test1() {
        when(service.getById(anyString())).thenReturn(responseDto());

        mockMvc
            .perform(
                get("/endpoint", "id")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(equalToJson(FileUtils.readSystemResource("expectedresponse.json"))));
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    @AutoConfigureDataJpa
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Controller.class,
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        includeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                value = Controller.class
            )
        }
    )
    static class TestConfig {

    }

}
```

This test will ran OK, but if I remove `@AutoConfigureDataJpa` from `TestConfig` it will fail with

````
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:348)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:82)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$0(NodeTestTask.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:69)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#493968a9' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#493968a9': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1665)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:830)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#493968a9': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:662)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 80 more
    ```
````

Comment: Because your controller uses a repository?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli
nope, controller use only service which are mocked

Comment: Why do you use the TestConfig ? It's not necessary

Comment: Please add your main spring boot application

Comment: Same issue here Spring Boot 2.2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same issue, maybe you have quite similar.

My WebApplication Class looked before:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({InfraConfiguration.class}) // needs EntityManager
public class WebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I splitted up ApplicationClass and ConfigurationClass like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And a configuration class on same package:

```
@Configuration
@Import({InfraConfiguration.class}) // needs EntityManager
public class WebConfiguration {}
```

Hope that helps. My MvcTests now working again.